# NetFT - Validation Failed - SMB Network Path Not Found

Tags: windows-server-2019, server-message-block, failovercluster

Two new Windows Server 2019 Datacenter edition servers setup in a Failover Cluster, cluster validation is failing at 'Validate CSV Settings' as follows:

> Validating Server Message Block (SMB) share access through the IP
> address of the fault tolerant network driver for failover clustering
> (NetFT), and connecting with the user account associated with
> validation.
>
> Begin Cluster Shared Volumes support testing on node HV-01.***.local.
>
> Begin Cluster Shared Volumes support testing on node HV-02.***.local.
>
> Validating Server Message Block (SMB) share access through the IP
> address of the fault tolerant network driver for failover clustering
> (NetFT), and connecting with the Cluster Shared Volumes test user
> account.
>
> Validating access using Server Message Block (SMB) protocol from node
> HV-01.*** .local to a share on node HV-02.***.local.
>
> For the new Server Message Block (SMB) share, a connection was
> successfully made by using the Cluster Shared Volumes test user
> account, from node HV-01.*** .local to the share on node
> HV-02.***.local.
>
> Validating access using Server Message Block (SMB) protocol from node
> HV-02.*** .local to a share on node HV-01.***.local.
>
> Failed to validate Server Message Block (SMB) share access through the
> IP address of the fault tolerant network driver for failover
> clustering (NetFT). The connection was attempted with the Cluster
> Shared Volumes test user account, from node HV-02.*** .local to the
> share on node HV-01.***.local. The network path was not found.

Validation passes going from HV-01 over to HV-02 but not the other way around.
A few days of banging my head into the keyboard I am asking for help.

I can access shares between each server from each server.
The cluster was working, it sat there for a few weeks while I was working on another project and now I came back and nothing would live migrate off of HV-01 and onto HV-02.

Any suggestions before I blow the servers away and start from scratch?